# How to go about learning R-tree?

Tags: indexing, r-tree

I'm currently taking part in a "Data modeling" course. And for my final project, I need to make a research about "R-tree index for spatial searching". However, I'm not at all familiar with many concepts concerning the subject matter (spatial data, multi-dimentional data,...).So, I read the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) and as I encountered new concepts, I tried to learn them on the way. 
However, I don't think this top-down approach is a very efficient way to go about this. Thus, I'd really appreciate it if anybody can suggest a way/lists of things that I need to read up in advance, in order to understand R-tree, and hopefully make some kind of implementation out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the original [paper](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/SI-LS/papers/Gut84.pdf) and check out (shameless self promotion) a [basic R-Tree implementation in Java](https://github.com/rweeks/util/blob/master/src/com/newbrightidea/util/RTree.java].).